# Linked server issue while migrating shards from SQL Server 2005 to 2008 Enterprise R1

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, migration

I am facing a strange problem during data migration. We "restored" data from 3 shards(on diff SQL Server 2005 machines) to single SQL Server 2008. We have single 2008 server now but the shards are unchanged from 2005.

Now I am trying to exec a SP on Master but I get the following error

> Creating SP
>   OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Login timeout expired".
>   OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "(null)" returned message "A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.".
>   Msg 53, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
>   Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53].

All shards are on SQL Server. We are not using SQLNCLI10 provider. But it's strange to see this error.

My SP use some dynamically created distributed queries in SP. 
eg. **Shard01.dbo.Update.....**

What could possible go wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. 
My SP was using a view which was moved restored from 2005 to 2008. 2008 has different shards configurations and SQLNCLI10 was used for OPENROWSET in 2005 but not in 2008 as all the DBs were on same server.

Redefining the view solved the issue.